# Get ID from REST call then use it in another REST call Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

I'm trying to achieve this:
I have a call to a REST api and getting an ID, after that I'm using that ID to call another REST API and get data from it for the selected ID. I have to use the same ID to do more REST calls on the same angular view.

This is how my code inside a controller looks like:

```
.controller("ReservationCtrl", function($scope, $stateParams, Reservations, Clients, Apartments) {
    // Getting ID from  URL & $state
    $scope.currentReservation = Reservations.get({ reservationId: $stateParams.reservationId });

    // I'm trying to get guest data by forwarding an ID from the currentReservation, but I'm getting angular error
    $scope.guest = Clients.get({ clientId: currentReservation.clients_id });

    // The same situation here, but now, as a function which I'm calling from the view I can get the ID, but when I call it from a pressed button, not from ng-init...
    $scope.apartment = function(id){
            return Apartments.get({apartmentId: apartments_id});
    };
});
```

So, as I wrote in the code, I can get the data, when I call the apartment function from the view, only using a button, which I have to click to load the data, so this is not useful..

Any way to solve this? 
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue by the help of @Adrian Smith's answer, so thanks @Adrian Smith. I have used Angular's $promise to run other calls.

So here is the code which works well for me:

```
.controller("ReservationCtrl", function($scope, $stateParams, Reservations, Clients, Apartments) {
Reservations.get({ reservationId: $stateParams.reservationId })
.$promise.then(function(res){
    $scope.guest = Clients.get({ clientId: res.clients_id });
    $scope.apartment = Apartments.get({apartmentId: res.apartments_id});
    // .. and so on for every request which includes an ID from the Reservations REST call.
});
```

Answer (score -1):

We can't see the inside of your services, but I'm guessing that those services return a promise, not a value. The issues is that $scope.currentReservation.client_id isn't assigned when Clients.get tries to run.

Also several variables aren't preceded by scope, but I'm assuming that was just a typo.

This modified controller should fix both issues.

```
.controller("ReservationCtrl", function($scope, $stateParams, Reservations, Clients, Apartments) {
    // Getting ID from  URL & $state
    Reservations.get({ reservationId: $stateParams.reservationId })
    .then(function(res) {
      $scope.currentReservation = res;
    })
    .then(Clients.get({ clientId: $scope.currentReservation.clients_id }))
    .then(function(res) {
      $scope.guest = res;
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.error("Error: ", err);
    })

    // The same situation here, but now, as a function which I'm calling from the view I can get the ID, but when I call it from a pressed button, not from ng-init...
    $scope.apartment = function(id){
            return Apartments.get({apartmentId: $scope.apartments_id});
    };
});
```

Comment: Hey @Adrian Smith, Thanks for the answer, unfortunately it doesn't work for me, but It reminded me to try with $promise, so it is working now.